# Median excluding negative and non numeric values in vba excel

Tags: vba, excel

I can do the following to get the median in a range of values, excluding negative and non-numeric values in excel:

```
=MEDIAN(IF(ISNUMBER(B1:B8),IF(B1:B8>0,ROUND(B1:B8,2))))
```

How to accomplish the above but in vba excel?

Data can be, numbers, "N/A" phrase, and negative values,

example:
12, 2, -4, N/A, 3, 4

Comment: Something with this formula does not add up, it does not calc the median for B1:B8, as you seem to intend it to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as a very quick solution, you can use the worksheet-functions directly in vba.

This would be an example of your formula as vba

```
Dim myValue As Variant
Dim myRange As Range
Set myRange = Range("B1:B8")
With Application.WorksheetFunction
  myValue = 0
  If .IsNumber(myRange(1, 1).Value) Then
     If myRange(1, 1) > 0 Then
       myValue = .Round(myRange(1, 1), 2)
     End If
  End If
  Debug.Print .Median(myValue)
End With
```

However, I don't think, that this is quite what you are aiming for. Maybe you can give a better example of your data then, to test this on.

**Edit: This works quite nice**

```
Sub jookCalc()
  Dim myValues() As Variant
  Dim myRange() As Variant
  Dim i As Long
  myRange = Range("B1:B8")
  With Application.WorksheetFunction
      ReDim myValues(LBound(myRange, 1) To LBound(myRange, 1))
      For i = LBound(myRange, 1) To UBound(myRange, 1)
        If .IsNumber(myRange(i, 1)) Then
           If myRange(i, 1) > 0 Then
             myValues(UBound(myValues)) = .Round(myRange(i, 1), 2)
             ReDim Preserve myValues(LBound(myRange, 1) To UBound(myValues) + 1)
           End If
        End If
      Next i
      Debug.Print .Median(myValues)
  End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Jook I'm getting a Type mismatch at `if .isnumber(myRange) then`, actually, i was trying to do the same thing, but getting the same result :(

Comment: ah - doh - of course  `myRange` or more explicit `myRange.Value` is an Array! you need to specify an exact value

Comment: but you see, this is why I suspect your formula is not doing what you expect in the first place. You should create an array or range of values, which fit your criteria and should end up with code or formula like `.Median(myRange)`

Comment: yeap, that's why, but since I have a range of values, then I'll have to make a loop to check each one of them, right?

Comment: it would be easier if it would have a conditional median like the averageifs `= Application.WorksheetFunction.AverageIfs(.Range("Y5:Y" & CStr(i)), .Range("Y5:Y" & CStr(i)), ">=0", .Range("Y5:Y" & CStr(i)), "<>N/A")`

Comment: yeah - I am sure there might be an easier solution to this, than what I came up with, but it works. I am interested in alternatives too ;) Maybe there would be a better attempt to this by reffering more to the calculation of median.